# Php display content after login

Tags: php, session

I don't know how to get to the main page index.php and show some div's with javascript function after i check if the login data is correct. I run login.php scrip after the user clicks on submit button, and than if user data is correct i want to show some div's with javascript and stay on index.php page. I tried this using javascript function and than the header(location: ./index.php) in php but it didn't work.

My code:

```
if($name == $username && $pass == $password){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
        , 'showDiv();'
        , '</script>';
    header("Location: ./index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `session_start();` at the top of your `login.php` and `index.php` files, then put this in your `login.php` file:

```
if ($name == $username && $pass == $password) { 
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
    header("Location: ./index.php");
}
```

Then, on your `index.php` file, do this to see if the user is logged in:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['authenticated']) && $_SESSION['authenticated']) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
    . 'showDiv();'
    . '</script>'; # If you want your div to show on your index.php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using seems weird. A better approach would be to use SESSION variables to store login info(when user logs in) and display content after checking the SESSION variable like this:-

```
if(isset($_SESSION['somevalue']))
{
echo 'whatever you want';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your login.php write this.

```
session_start();

if($name == $username && $pass == $password){ 
    $_SESSION['somevalue'] = $username;
    header("Location: ./index.php");
}
```

In index.php You need to check whether your session is set or not? If set show youw div with javascript code.

session_start();

```
if(isset($_SESSION['somevalue']))
{
    //show your div code here.
}
```

Comment: I got the error: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($name == $username && $pass == $password)
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
```

Now anyhwhere in code first start session and check for login name session variable.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['login'] ) && $_SESSION['login'] === true)
{
   //do what logged in user require 
}
else
{
  // redirect them to login page with proper error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write session_start(); in first line of your login.php file. Because some time it has problem.

```
session_start(); // line 1 in login.php

if($name == $username && $pass == $password)
{ 
  $_SESSION['mydata'] = $username;
  header("Location: ./index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to use some Jquery and an Ajax call in order to not refresh the page once the user clicked the submit button.

The code you need is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   'url': 'http://yourdomain.com/authentication_script.php',
   'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Basic " + encodeBase64(username + ":" + password)
  },
  sucess: function(result) {
   alert('authenticated'); // here you can add some other functions to execute once authenticated
}
});
```

The idea is that you should take care that in the authentication script you should also include session variables and keep track of the user data as long as you / he want/s.